# jquery - Get a class name that start with block_ from several classes

Tags: jquery, css, class

The HTML would look like `<div class="someClass class_2 otherClass">`, I want to get the name of class_2, so that I can use the number 2 in my fadeIn code.

```
$('#main [class*="class_"]').click(function() {

    $('.pop_over.block_'+number).fadeIn()

});
```

Comment: You shouldn't store data in a class. Try using something like `data-something="2"` and getting it with `$(this).data("something")`

Comment: I knew I was doing something the wrong way round. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the element

```
$(this).attr('class') //will give string of all classes ex. "someClass class_2 otherClass"
```

So you have to find the "class_x"

```
var str = $(this).attr('class');
var index = $(this).attr('class').indexOf('class_');
var ourClass = $(this).attr('class').substr(index, 7); //this will give you the class_2 only
```

then, when you have the name of the class use something like this:

```
parseInt(ourClass[ourClass.length - 1]); //2 in integer
```

But, you might consider using "data-" attribute. Add data-my-value="2", and get it by using attr jQuery method:

```
parseInt($('some element').attr('data-my-value'));
```

Comment: An alternative to `$(elem).attr("data-my-value")` is `$(elem).data("myValue")`. See http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5